# How to forward IP packets with Ruby

Tags: ruby, networking, udp

I want to capture packets whoes has a special target ip, then forward these packets by UDP. Does Ruby can do this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Packet, you mean? If you want see packets in userspace, not kernel-level then you can use several ways.

1. libpcap: libpcap is packet capture library used in tcpdump/wireshark
2. libipq: iptables packet queueing library. http://rubyipq.rubyforge.org/
   for libipq, there is also ruby binding but it doesn't seems to be in activated.
   Actually libipq is deprecated by libnetfilter_queue

You can make ruby binding of libnetfilter_queue.